# Bootcamp stuck at: Please wait while boot camp assistant is removing the partitions it created

Tags: bootcamp, partition, filevault, mojave

I am trying to **install windows 10** as dual boot on my macbook pro 2017, running mac os mojave (10.14) using bootcamp assistant.

It runs normally and then in the end where it removes the temporary partitions it created, it gets stuck, for hours and hours.

I have:

1. Tried running the process **multiple times**.
2. **Filevault is not active** (never was)
3. **Restarted** the system many times (which removes the partitions, including windows one too, maybe because the process didn't complete?

This is the `diskutil list` dump from **terminal**:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         340.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                152.0 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +340.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            63.6 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                508.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +4.7 GB     disk2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +1.2 GB     disk3
```

The error image looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update:**

It got fixed after mac os mojave developer beta 2 update.

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered the same issue as you and have resolved it.

The issue for me was caused because I am using a windows ISO that contains x86 and x64 versions which is too big for the small reserve space bootcamp sets aside for the install ISO. Get a version that is specific to what you need x64 OR x86

anyway, you need to make a backup of your mac on a hard drive, using Time Machine is fine and the easiest way. Or simple remove your critical files and set up from fresh.

REBOOT
HOLD COMMAND+R
ENTER DISK UTILITY

You need to find the master drive for the hard drive that has the issue. (you can select view all drives/volumes on the top left if you don't see it straight away.

My drive was something like "APPLE SSD0256R DRIVE"

click ERASE and name it exactly as you see the name written before . (It should be MAC OS JOURNALED from the drop down menu too) Now click ERASE again to confirm.

You will now have restored the drive to a single partition.

QUIT DISK UTILITY

Now proceed to use time machine to restore or reinstall Mac OS from the previous menu.

That will put you back in the state before attempting to install windows.

P.S. I did try to use the command line options as mentioned elsewhere but they just would not work for me so this was the only way. 
Hope you get it all sorted!
_/_

Comment: Also, this could save you a lot of time. If the bootcamp just failed and you haven't been tinkering with anything in the terminal you could try this simple technique.

Go to DISK UTILITY and select MACINTOSH HD click PARTITION and PARTITION again (don't worry you're not going to erase your data)

You should see two small segments that are BOOTCAMP and OSX RESERVED. highlight them and click the - button. 

Do that for both of the partitions and then select APPLY in the corner.  

Disk utility will merge the partitions back into one and all should be good!

If you get an error then ^

Comment: my install is: Win10_1803_English_x64.iso (only 64bit), and no it removes the partitions it created on next reboot, so no issues there, do i still need to do the partition step?

Comment: @Anthony Your answer should be accepted answer.